# Mysql Take select * statement and turn it in to a delete statement

Tags: mysql, join

I crafted a select statement that pulls from 9 tables.

```
select * 
from calls 
join cases using (tid) 
join case_history using (tid) 
join calls_audio_deleted using (tid) 
join audio_files using (tid) 
join windows using (audio_file_id) 
join labels using (window_id) 
join features using (window_id) 
join prs_info using (tid);
```

How do I go about turning this in to a delete statement.  I wanted to add the clause where tid in (11, 12 ,13 ,14 .....);

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete calls, cases, case_history, audio_files, windows, labels, features, prs_info
from calls 
join cases using (tid) 
join case_history using (tid) 
join calls_audio_deleted using (tid) 
join audio_files using (tid) 
join windows using (audio_file_id) 
join labels using (window_id) 
join features using (window_id) 
join prs_info using (tid)
where calls.tid in (11, 12 ,13 ,14 .....);
```

Comment: You need 15 rep to upvote. But if that solved your problem you can accept that answer with the checkmark under the vote counter.